# MediaElement.js - Best cross-browser filetype/encoding to use?

Tags: video, html5-video, video-encoding, mediaelement.js

I've implemented a video player in my website using MediaElement.js. Users can upload videos to the site, and the player allows them to watch the videos in-browser on the site.

I've run into issues, however, with different browsers being able to play certain formats, but not others. For example, MP4 files have been a bit spotty, working fine on some browsers, but not playing on others. I believe this is happening because not every browser supports every video codec.

I've been thinking that I should recommend users upload videos in a particular format/encoding that will be able to be played in a cross-browser environment on both Mac and Windows. My question is: Are there any formats that are playable by MediaElement.js in all browsers? If so, which should I recommend my users upload?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realize this is an old question, but hopefully this answer will be helpful for anyone else that runs into this problem.

Here are the settings that the creator of the plugin recommends:
http://johndyer.name/ffmpeg-settings-for-html5-codecs-h264mp4-theoraogg-vp8webm/

Using FFMPEG and the aforementioned settings rendered videos that worked in all major browsers.

Comment: Thanks, I never really found an answer for this one when I asked it, so this is helpful to know!